# How Can I Extract a Cell's value that is connected to a column from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

pretty new to python, I have a question regarding dataframes.
So currently what I have is two different dataframes. One of them goes like this:

There is a problem regarding the table format so I am posting an image [image]

The other one goes like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 513 |  |
| 2 | 513 |  |
| 3 | 730 |  |

What I need to get is, to extract the value from the first dataframe that matches the second dataframe's respected rows. For example:The first row of the second dataframe matches 1 to 513, and the value that corresponds this match in the first dataframe is 1.8. For second row in the second dataframe, the match is 2 to 513, and the value that corresponds in the first dataframe is 2. How can I extract these values in a pythonic way?

My current code is like this:

```
data = first_dataframe    
B = second_dataframe['B'].tolist()

for i in range(954):
    for j in B:
        output = data.iat[i, j]
        print(output)
```

unfortunately what I'm getting is every single value of the first column of the first dataframe matching with all the values of the first row in the first dataframe. What should I change? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please format the Frist table also as table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataFrame1:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({
    1:[0.5,0.4,0.1],
    2:[0.6,0.2,0.5],
    3:[0.5,0.4,0.7],
    513:[1.8,2,5],
}, index=[1,2,3]).stack().to_frame(name="C")
```

DataFrame2:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({
    "A":[1,2,3],
    "B":[513,513,730],
}, index=[1,2,3])
```

Merge:

```
df2.merge(df1,left_on=["A","B"],right_index=True)
```

Result:
| |a|b|c|
|--|--|--|--|
|1|1|513|1.8|
|2|2|513|2.0|

hope this is what you want?

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you so much. Could you please explain the code and its functions?

Comment: yeah sure,
I have Pandas DataFrames. The [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) function transforms the Columns to data in rows. [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) is simply a join. Hope this helps you? I have linked the documentation from Pandas to the functions